# How to perform Welch's Ttest in Spark 2.0.0 using StreamingTest

Tags: scala, apache-spark, statistics, rdd

I want to try Welch's T-test in Spark 2.0.0

As I know I can use **StreamingTest()** from mllib
on this website.
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.StreamingTest]

**this is my code in spark-shell**

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.{BinarySample, StreamingTest}  
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext,SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(30))

ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint")

val data = ssc.textFileStream("/datatest/sample1.csv").map(line => line.split(",") match {
      case Array(label, value) => BinarySample(label.toBoolean, value.toDouble)
    })

val streamingTest = new StreamingTest().setPeacePeriod(0).setWindowSize(0).setTestMethod("welch")

val out = streamingTest.registerStream(data)
out.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

and the sample1.csv will be like this

```
TRUE,11
FALSE,43
FALSE,2
TRUE,5
TRUE,3
TRUE,4
TRUE,122
TRUE,153
FALSE,153
FALSE,151
TRUE,153
TRUE,154
...
```

and I got this error.

```
18/01/17 15:50:30 WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:192)
        at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.size(SeqLike.scala:106)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.size(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.mutable.Builder$class.sizeHint(Builder.scala:69)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder.sizeHint(ArrayBuilder.scala:22)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.findNewFiles(FileInputDStream.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.compute(FileInputDStream.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.StateDStream.compute(StateDStream.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ShuffledDStream.compute(ShuffledDStream.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

I think the sample1.csv data is wrong for applying to parameter of StreamingTest.registerStream()

I can't not understand what kind of data is required for parameter.

or I just found another one
**WelchTTest().**
I don't know yet what it is different.
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/stat/test/WelchTTest.html]